# How to loop through each JSON object with SwiftyJSON, and get values from each object?

Tags: json, swift, loops, alamofire

I'm trying to use SwiftyJSON with the Spoonacular API to do some recipe app.

I'm a beginner developer, so I'm having troubles iterating through the JSON response results. I am combining SwiftyJSON with Alamofire.

The API results looks like this:

```
    "results": [
{
"id": 548450,
"title": "Sweet Potato Kale Pizza with Rosemary & Red Onion",
"image": "https://spoonacular.com/recipeImages/548450-312x231.jpg",
"imageType": "jpg"
},
{
"id": 759293,
"title": "Deep-Dish Skillet Pizza",
"image": "https://spoonacular.com/recipeImages/759293-312x231.jpg",
"imageType": "jpg"
},
```

I want to go through each recipe result, and get the ID and title. How do I do this?

From googling, most people suggest something like:

```
            for (key, subJson) in json {
            let id = json["results"][index]["id"].stringValue
            let title = json["results"][index]["title"].stringValue
            print(id)
            print(title)
        }
```

As you can see, I'm having troubles accessing each index in the JSON response. The code above seems to loop through each key (in this case there's 4, id, title, image and imageType) so it won't go through each index.

I'm just having troubles figuring out how to iterate through each index, when I believe a JSON created from the response data isn't a normal array

Comment: Why don't you use codable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case something like this should work:

```swift
let results = json["results"].arrayValue
let identifiers = results.map { $0["id"].stringValue }
let titles = results.map { $0["title"].stringValue }
```

However like @Frankenstein already mentioned, you're most likely better off creating [Decodable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/decodable) models in combination with [JSONDecoder](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsondecoder).